# Looking for suggestions for installing Cartaro on a web hosting service

Tags: geoserver, cartaro

Hello maybe a basic question, but i am trying to install Cartaro or add geo-enabled tools on a web hosting service. I am looking for options anyhow I only have found the one offered by AcuGIS.

Finally the question is where can I do this task? Any suggestion is very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally speaking, I love GeoServer - http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome - and it might be an option for you. To quote from the website - it is now quite widely adopted open source software that allows you to share and edit geospatial data. Fully supportive of the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Web Feature Service (WFS) and Web Coverage Service (WCS) standards, as well as a high performance certified compliant Web Map Service (WMS).

There is a thriving stack exchange community Geographic Information systems - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions - where GeoServer is very widely discussed.

Other options might include:

http://mapserver.org/ -  which is an Open Source platform for publishing spatial data and interactive mapping applications to the web.

Proprietary options are also available, including ArcGIS, PBS's Spectrum Spatial and Autodesk's Map Server 2013 to name a few.

Hope this helps.
Morgan

Answer (score 0):

geOps, the main makers of Cartaro offers Cartaro hosting services too. You may contact us directly.